# Find a field that doesn't contain a certain class

Tags: jquery, class

In my program I have two input fields that *must* have the same ID, so when I am trying to insert data from my datebase into the second input field my program wants to replace the first id's field.

Because the two fields have the same Id I can't use the standard mechanism for referencing by Id.

```
document.getElementById()
```

I do not have access to the HTML file so my idea was to use jQuery to add a class to the first field in the same code section that is giving it value and then find the second field by finding the id that dosent have the added class.

Would this be the correct approach in this werid example and if so any clarification on how this would look? Thank you

Comment: I need to understand how or why you have two fields with the same Id? To an experienced HTML developer, this is a very strange scenario you are describing... The Id (Identifier) is the unique access to the tags on the page, so it makes sense that you describe the database populating both fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ids are unique, and no more than one element should have the same Id, For this approach there are some options like using `data-` attribute or `class`es as you said.

I myself would go with classes just like you.

Comment: Ok, I added unique classes and calling on the inputs with these, thank you for your feedback!